# Does spring always ensure same creation order for independent beans?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-bean

Let's say, I have 4 beans like,

```
@Component
public class Bean11 {

  @PostConstruct
  public void post(){
   System.out.println("I am bean # 1");
  }
}

@Component
public class Bean2 {

  @PostConstruct
  public void post(){
   System.out.println("I am bean # 2");
  }
}

@Component
public class Bean3 {

  @PostConstruct
  public void post(){
   System.out.println("I am bean # 3");
  }
}

@Component
public class Bean4 {

  @PostConstruct
  public void post(){
   System.out.println("I am bean # 4");
  }
}
```

none of these are dependent on each other. Will their creation always be in the same order or will spring just randomly instantiate them?

Comment: I don't think you can depend on it doing this. And even if it does instantiate them based on the order that they appear, how are you going to write a test to make sure that they appear in the correct order? In the long run if you depend on this behavior, I would expect it to bite you sooner or later.

Comment: That is my fear. The reason I am trying to understand the expected behavior of spring.

Comment: Your best bet is to build your app in such a way that the order doesn't matter.